# Pytest: use App conftest.py in framework tests

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I'm trying to run splinter test cases using pytest. I have an app and a framework, and they both have defined test cases. When I start running the tests my app also runs the framework's test cases using the "main" function (from _pytest.config import main `main([<framework_dir>, args, ...])`).

The problem is that I want to use the app conftest.py and not the framework's conftest.py. I have tried to achieve that by using --confcutdir= option  (`main([<framework_dir>, '--confcutdir={}'.format(os.path.dirname(__file__)), ...])`) but it doesn't work. When I list the fixtures (with --fixtures option) they are not listed (the ones that are defined in app's `conftest.py`).

So does anyone have any experience how to share fixtures between app and framework/lib?

I have created a GitHub repo that simulates my project and reproduces the error: https://github.com/karantan/global-fixtures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a lot of help on this on websauna IRC chat by the user "enkidulan". He pointed out that I shouldn't be calling framework tests via the `main` function.

The root of my problem was the [strategy of pytests discovery of fixtures functions](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#shifting-visibility-of-fixture-functions) seems like the closest to test files `conftest.py` always wins in overwrite competition, even in case if `-p` specifies some fixtures to load (not sure if it is a bug in pytests).

So he suggested that I should rename `conftest.py` to something different, like `fixtures.py` (which I did). And then instead of discovering just the App tests (`pytest src/app/tests/`) I also discover framework tests + add which fixtures to use: `pytest -p app.tests.fixtures src/app/tests/`

NOTE: the repo is updated with the last working version if anyone wants to check how the code looks.